# How to remove the state value when screen is changed in react native

Tags: react-native

I am making an react native android app in which componentWillUnmount() does not works.Suppose user enters a text value in a text input in particular screen and goes to next screen.After that when user presses back button then i want that text value written in text input to be removed.I tries by adding this line in my code.

```
 componentWillUnmount(){
  this.setState({text:""})
  }
```

Basically i was removing the state value which i put in TextInput.But this does not works.Same this is happening in case of activity indicator.When activity indicator start to fetch data then first i check if connected to internet or not.If not then by navigation i navigate to no network screen.But from there when i presses back button then activity indicator does not go away ? So how can i remove all the value of state in a component after navigating to different screen?

Comment: Did you check if the componentWillUnmount is executing? Probably you are just pushing the new screen to the screen's stack so is still there. What I would do in this case is work with Redux for state management. Is much easier to manage

Comment: What dependency are you using for navigation?

Comment: react navigation ! i uses createDrawerNavigator and createStackNavigator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React Navigation allows you to add listeners so you track actions that are happening to the screen.

There are four listeners that you can add:

> - `willFocus` - the screen will focus
> - `didFocus` - the screen focused (if there was a transition, the transition completed)
> - `willBlur` - the screen will be unfocused
> - `didBlur` - the screen unfocused (if there was a transition, the transition completed)

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle

Here is an example of calling the `willBlur`, the others follow the same pattern you just change the value that is passed to the function.

```
componentDidMount () {
   this.didBlurSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
   'didBlur',
   payload => {
    // you can perform actions here when the screen `willBlur`
    this.setState({text: ''});
   }
 );
}

componentWillUnmount () {
 // remember to unsubscribe
 if (this.didBlurSubscription) {
   this.didBlurSubscription.remove();
 }
}
```

The reason your current solution is not working is that the screen isn't being unmounted it is going in and out of focus/blur. So the `componentWillUnmount` will not be called. Also if the component is being unmounted then you should not be trying to setState as that is an anitpattern and can lead to memory leaks.